# From page to page navigation why @postconstruct init() method is called twice?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a following situation. I am trying to pass a parameter from one bean (e.g. fooBean) to another bean (e.g. barBean) when a page to a page navigation occurrs.

Both beans are ViewScoped.

The fooBean is created when a foo.xhtml page is loaded. From there I pass a parameter "id" to bar.xhtml page.

This is foo.xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{fooBean.items}" ....>
        <p:column ..>
            <h:commandLink action="#{fooBean.next}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item.id}" target="#{barBean.newId}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This is fooBean.next() method:

```
public String next()  { return "bar.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" }
```

When I click h:commandLink (record or row) from foo.xhtml page, it is redirected to "bar.xhtml".

This is barBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BarBean implements ... {

    private String newId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { ... }

    // getter and setter for newId
}
```

I noticed that @PostConstruct init() method of barBean is triggered twice. With first call/trigger, I was expecting that this.newId variable of the barBean would be set to passed value (e.g. id=12345) which it did by checking log statements (setter is called and this.newId = 12345).

Then init() method is triggered again but I thought this.newId would retain the passed value but it becomes null.

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Does your `CarBean` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes BarBean implements serializable. I read a thread in here that it could be related to a known  jsf 2.0.4 bug. Viewscope is behaving as request scope. That is my  guess for now.